# Array element type assertion problem in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

```js
type Plan<T> = [T[], ...T[]];
```

I declared a type named `Plan`, which includes a repetitive plan in index `0` and in the rest what to execute initially.

example) `const life: Plan<string> = [ ["getUp", "work", "sleep"], "birth", "grow" ]`

And I tried to define the following function:

```js
function parsePlan<T>(plan: Plan<T>, index: number): T {
    if(index < 1) throw Error();

    return index < plan.length
    ?plan[index]
    :plan[0][(index-plan.length)%(plan[0].length)]
}
```

but It says there is a problem that this would return `T | T[]`.

If `index < 1` it will `throw Error()` and that makes it impossible to return `T[]`.

Why does this error appear, and how can I fix this error?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type narrowing doesn't work in all cases, as you expect.

It does work on a single variable though, when you add type guards or type predicates to narrow down.

This will work:

```
type Plan<T> = [T[], ...T[]];

function parsePlan<T>(plan: Plan<T>, index: number): T {
    const item = plan[index]

    if (Array.isArray(item)) throw Error();

    return index < plan.length ? item : plan[0][(index-plan.length)%(plan[0].length)]
}
```

Also playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQwHYB4AqA+KBeKBtNPAXQBooA6SwoogbgCh6AzAVyQGNgBLAeySjAIATgGcI8ZOgwAKMIiQAuWPKlkuSACYQAHkqQsAtgCMIQgJRK0UAN70o9qOz4jgULsAgGcA+XnVbtIkYHNyYoaQBBISEEEHIuESiYkGl3TzMzKGAACyEeAHcoAFFoniFpMwY7ByEIYBYhfn8dKBQfZHI4CCQAcxyoAH43Dy8lOWQ8AAYiPFTNHQBacaRO7r7sswBSWV9p1d6csyCAXyA).